# Can you still make QuickTime to store temporary recordings on another drive?

Tags: quicktime

I need to get QuickTime Player to store its temporary files on another disk. I found an answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139525/how-do-i-get-quicktime-to-store-temporary-recordings-on-another-drive), which I tried, but QuickTime Player quits with an error when I try to make a Screen Recording. I used:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX
$ mv Data Data.bak
$ ln -s /Volumes/'Keeper 4'/QuicktimeScratch QTData
$ ln -s QTData Data
```

Does this no longer work, or did I screw something up? Keeper 4 is an external HD. I tried it with and without an existing QuicktimeScratch directory.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Apple doesn't want you to do this for whatever reason, so they prevent the symbolic link hack from working at the level of the `Data/` subdirectory. After fooling around with this, I found a workable solution one level up:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Containers/
$ mv com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/ com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX.backup/
$ ln -s /Volumes/<NAME_OF_VOLUME>/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/ .
```

No need for a double link trick this time around.