# Saving macOS Catalina Screen Recordings Cache to External Drive

Tags: macos, finder, catalina, filesystem, screen-capture

Im macOS Catalina, screen recordings are temporarily stored in `~Library/ScreenRecordings` before being saved on the target location. However, on systems with minimal available system storage, this can cause the recording to stop when disk space is full. Is there any way to link `~Library/ScreenRecordings` to an external drive such as `/Volumes/External\ Drive/ScreenRecordings`?

I have tried using symbolic links, however the screen recording crashed immediately. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following option:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Containers/
$ mv com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/ com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX.backup/
$ ln -s /Volumes/<NAME_OF_VOLUME>/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/ .
```

If the above option didn't help, then I would suggest you to:

Check the first [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/217264/341892) on this page shared by bmike.

Comment: As of macOS Catalina, the screen recordings are stored in `~/Library/ScreenRecordings`. This change was due to the fact that Apple introduced a system wide screen recording utility, called **Screenshot** located in `/Applications/Utilities/Screenshot.app`. Creating a symbolic link at `~/Library/ScreenRecordings` caused the Screenshot app to crash, but using QuickTime to start the screen recording successfully used the symbolic link at `~/Library/ScreenRecordings` pointing to the external drive. Is there any reason why the Screenshot app does not work with symbolic links and QuickTime does?